# Measure of noncompactness

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $\dim X<\infty$, $A$ be a bounded subset of $X$ and $\alpha$ be Kuratowski measure of noncompactness. How to prove that $\alpha (A) =0$ if and only if $A$ is relatively compact?

Answer (score 2):

By definition of ball mesure of non-compactness
$$
\beta(A)=\inf\left\{r>0:\quad\exists\{B(x_i,r)\}_{i=1}^n\quad A\subset\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nB(x_i,r)\right\}
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
\beta(A)=0
&\;\overset{\text{definition of infimum}}{\Longleftrightarrow}\;
\forall\varepsilon>0\;\;\exists\{B(x_i,\varepsilon)\}_{i=1}^n\;\;A\subset\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n B(x_i,\varepsilon)\\
&\;\overset{\begin{array}{cc}\text{definition of relative}\\ \text{compactness}\end{array}}{\Longleftrightarrow}\;
 A \quad\text{is relatively compact}
\end{align}
$$
It remains to recall that $\beta(A)\leq\alpha(A)\leq 2\beta(A)$. Note that condition $\mathrm{dim}\; X<\infty$ is redundant here.

Comment: Actually, the definition of Kuratowski measure seems to work also in a metric space.

Comment: If $\dim X=\infty$ then how we prove this theorem.

Comment: @user45631 My prood holds for all cases: for $\mathrm{dim}\; X<\infty$ and for $\mathrm{dim}\; X=\infty$

Comment: @Norbert This is the definition of Hausdorff measure of noncompactness NOT Kuratowski measure of noncompactness

Comment: @Mokata, fixed it.

Comment: @Norbert In the last equivalence(definition of relative compactness), I can understand this $\Leftarrow  $, but why we have the other one?

Comment: @Mokata, you should read this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space)